# What makes HashMap.containsKey() have a constant time complexity while ArrayList.contains() has a linear time complexity in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, search, memory, time

In other words, how can Map.containsKey() search without iterating over the elements in proper sequence like List.contains() does, which is what makes List.contains() have a linear time complexity?

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(1);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(3);
    list.add(4);
    list.add(5);
    list.contains(5); // Linear Time Complexity
Map<Integer, Character> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(1,'a');
    map.put(2,'b');
    map.put(3,'c');
    map.put(4,'d');
    map.put(5,'e');
    map.containsKey(5); // Only Constant Time Complexity
```

Comment: Have a look at the implementation of `HashMap.containsKey()`, or just at the theory of HashMaps in general. Did you do any research before asking this question?

Comment: FYI, your question is ill-premised, in that `Map` and `List` are interfaces with many implementations. It's possible to have an implementation of `Map.containsKey` that takes linear time, and it's possible to have an implementation of `List.contains` that takes constant time. So you need to ask about `HashMap` and `ArrayList` specifically.

Comment: @tgdavies yes, that is the implementation in my example. Also, I am asking how a search of an implementation of Map can achieve constant time. Many, if not all, implementations of the Map interface in Java have methods that are able to search in constant time. Also, the link you provided does not address this.

Comment: @ruakh Many, if not all, implementations of the Map interface in Java have methods that are able to search in constant time, or else they might not be a "map". I gave a specific implementation for both Map and List in my example, which you acknowledged in your comment.

Comment: @tgdavies it's ok for beginners to ask beginner questions. not everyone knows the right keywords to search for to find what they want.

Comment: The `HashMap` implementation, specifically, uses a hash table internally. The nature of a hash table means a lookup can happen in O(1) time, because all that matters is whether the bucket the key's hash falls into contains the key (though it gets a little more complicated when dealing with hash collisions). The "table" is an array, and if you know the index you want to look at then accessing the array is O(1). An `ArrayList` does not use a hash table. It just uses an array "as is". Therefore, it has to search the entire array linearly to see if it contains the element, which is an O(n) task.

Comment: @Slaw "if you know the index you want to look at then accessing the array is O(1)" I am asking about a search operation for a map and a list, more specifically a has map and an array list, I am not asking about an access operation.

Comment: As explained, the hash of the key is used to compute the index of the array to access. Accessing an array at a specific index is O(1). So, yes, you are implicitly asking about an access operation. Research hash tables and this will start to make more sense to you.

Comment: @Slaw HashMap.containsKey() and ArrayList.contains() are used when you do not know if the data structure contains an element, therefore you do not know the index or if it even exists, therefore you must search the data structure. I am asking about a search operation, not an access operation.

Comment: I recommend you research hash tables. What I'm saying will make much more sense if you understand how the implementation works. But again, the hash is computed from the key, and the index is computed from the hash. You are passing the key to the `containsKey` method as an argument. So, it _does_ know which index to search in the array. That's why I keep bringing up that accessing an array is O(1) time. You only ever look at one location; you don't search the entire array. That's different from an `ArrayList`, which _does_ search the array linearly.

Comment: @Slaw Ok, so that's more what I'm asking for, but really I'm asking how the "hash" algorithm that I did not create is able to produce the index of the key that I'm looking for when my input is NOT the index but the value at the index which is not known yet. But I will research hash tables. Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: A hash algorithm is simply something that takes an object and returns an integer. Ideally, every unique object would result in a different integer. Though that's not always possible. Now, in Java's `HashMap`, the hash is gotten by calling the `hashCode()` method on the key. Naively, the index would be computed by doing something like `int index = key.hashCode() % array.length`. Though `HashMap`, if I'm not mistaken, does some more advanced things to make the implementation better somehow.

Comment: @BrendanB: Many, but not all; for example, TreeMap.get and ConcurrentSkipListMap require logarithmic time. And EnumMap achieves constant time by a different principle, so it doesn't make sense to ask generically about how HashMap and EnumMap both manage it, unless you're OK with an answer that's vague enough to apply to both.

Answer (score 1):

This is just how those data structures are, well, structured.

The simpler case is the List. The List is basically a bunch of objects that point to their previous and next elements. No single List element knows where all of the other elements are, just its neighbors. So, if you want to figure out if a specific value is present, you have to go through the entire List and read their values. This means the operation is `O(n)`, or linear, in time.

For a Map, they typically use a hash to summarize a key and to tell the data structure where to put the key and value in the backing storage (the data structure that actually contains the keys and values).

The typical example of this is an array of Lists. You create an array index using `int arrayIndex = hash(key) % backingArray.length`. Then, you do `backingArray[arrayIndex].contains(value)`. Since it is unlikely for two keys to have the same `arrayIndex`, this `contains` call usually happens in `O(1)` time since the List only has one element, but since it's possible for there to be multiple elements in a worst-case scenario, it's actually `O(n)` in time for a true worst-case scenario.

`Map.containsKey` is only `O(1)` in time if the hashing function properly distributes the keys.

Comment: _"The List is basically a bunch of objects that point to their previous and next elements."_ that describes a linked list, which - at least in Java - is not something you should use.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel The Linked List is what is commonly taught in school, so it's what I talked about. When faced with a question from an obvious beginner, it's a good idea to answer from a beginner's perspective. I suppose the structure of the List isn't that important, though, since the main lack is an ability to go from value to location like the Map can.